# gstreamer error on mac

Tags: macos, video-streaming, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I have been working on my mac (version 10.10) and my raspberry pi (raspbian) to stream video feed live from my raspberry pi camera to my mac using gstreamer. On my mac, in terminal, I have been putting in the following code to receive the data from the raspberry pi over wifi:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v tcpclientsrc host=192.168.2.50 port=5000  ! gdpdepay !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false`

However I keep getting the error,
ERROR: pipeline could not be constructed: no element "tcpclientsrc". Has anyone run into this issue before and is it likely that I mis-downloaded a plugin causing this error? If someone has any better way of streaming video feed with low latency and less than a second of lag, I would appreciate links to guides. Any insight into this error would be useful, if you need more information to answer the question, just ask in the comments.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to install gst-plugins-base to get tcp plugins

if you use port to install your software

sudo port search gstreamer1

will list all the port related to gstreamer1

then you can install gstreamer1-gst-plugins-base

sudo port install gstreamer1-gst-plugins-base

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 14):

Thank you for your advice.
So, I did some more research and found a list of plugins that would help. With homebrew to get the extra plugins use the command:
`brew install gstreamer gst-libav gst-plugins-ugly gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-good`, which will get all of the needed plugins for streaming live video feed.